# Import private key and certificate into Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, ssl-certificate

I've just purchased a wildcard SSL cert (AlphaSSL) which I'd like to install on a box running Tomcat, to replace the existing SSL certificate.

I have the cert, the private key, the CA Root, the intermediate CA and so on.

I'm not too familiar with Tomcat so can anyone say with certainty what sequence I need to follow?

Here's the guide for creating a CSR from scratch that is specific to the appliance I'm using:

Thanks.

1. Back up your keystore

cp /opt/msw/data/keystore /root/keystoreBackup

2. Re-initialise the keystore

rm /opt/msw/data/keystore

3. Check the hostname

hostname appliance.inside6.com

4. Create a certificate for this machine

keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore /opt/msw/data/keystore -storepass changeit

What is your first and last name? [Unknown]: appliance.inside6.com

What is the name of your organizational unit? [Unknown]: Development

What is the name of your organization? [Unknown]: Clearswift

What is the name of your City or Locality? [Unknown]: Reading

What is the name of your State or Province? [Unknown]: Berkshire

What is the two-letter country code for this unit? [Unknown]: GB

Is CN=appliance.inside6.com, OU=Development, O=Clearswift, L=Reading, ST=Berkshire, C=GB correct? [no]: yes

Enter key password for  (RETURN if same as keystore password): {leaving the password blank here}

5. Generate the request keytool -certreq -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore /opt/msw/data/keystore -storepass changeit -file /root/certreq.csr

cat /root/certreq.csr

-----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST----- MIIBvjCCAScCAQAwfjELMAkGA1UEBhMCR0IxEjAQBgNVBAgTCUJlcmtzaGlyZTEQMA4GA1UEBxMH UmVhZGluZzETMBEGA1UEChMKQ2xlYXJzd2lmdDEUMBIGA1UECxMLRGV2ZWxvcG1lbnQxHjAcBgNV BAMTFWFwcGxpYW5jZS5pbnNpZGU2LmNvbTCBnzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOBjQAwgYkCgYEAncyI Ui4emCBqY1of4xUk0eJ8CcZtHaYyXrych5sFXTDFq9icRd2e4Xe94IvHlKZwtxAXsoZONXXo4gP2 jU5PKD/DMNlu2TtdISvxD4DstkYv9dpC+8bt5uftYQ405nHeRwPpBQornJz98f5tNiCIYRsB0gec 2Gj7J4TDf2+igYkCAwEAAaAAMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAA4GBAGVvifaZLvnwOYAdlblBMsSDAI1h VahtdzcLQrFzH3DezNfx5knqzzaM4oOC2N2RohMSKsP9DazqCFkj4i6lBS6M+X/inu0Hyp6b9fEz 06BJby+RM4nmv4RFXqdR5usIHalfodRxjWVHjMhN3FwiD1SPxXqLppp3zjEqhycVox/5
-----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----

6. Obtain a certificate from a commercial Certificate Authority such as Verisign.  During this phase you will have to paste/email the contents of /root/certreq.csr into an appropriate location
7. On the appliance, add the certificate the CA will have mailed you

keytool -import -alias tomcat -trustcacerts -keystore /opt/msw/data/keystore -storepass changeit -file /root/server.cert

Certificate reply was installed in keystore

8. Restart tomcat

uiservicecontrol restart tomcat

Comment: All sorted, bit of a workaround but I managed to do this on a Windows box using the new/improved Keytool that comes with jre6, I then copied the keystore over to the linux box.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is this for a Tomcat server:

1. Start with the original keystore that you used to create your CSR.   This keystore has on private key in it with the alias called "tomcat"
2. From your certificate reply you will have a reply-cert , a intermediate (probably) ,  and also a root cert that are 3 separate files.
3. use keytool -import  root cert with alias "root"
4. use keytool -import  intermediate cert with alias "intermediate"
5. finally  use keytool -import  cert-reply.crt into keystore with alias "tomcat".  this action imports the cert reply into position on top of the cert you generated when you created the keystore.  this action will generate a certificate chain of length 2 or 3
6. use keytool -list  to see the contents and the chain

NOTE: for an Apache server, [the steps are](http://jonausten.info/2011/12/08/create-your-own-self-signed-certificate-for-apache-on-windows/) a bit different.

Comment: What about for shared star certificates where the private key needs to be imported too?

Comment: If you want to edit my question and add additional detail OR , even better, add your own knowledgable answer, please do.

Comment: I was hoping you knew, since I'm fighting with one now.  :-)  When I figure it out, I'll try to remember to come back and add the info...

Comment: Have you tried downloading and installing 'KeystoreExplorer' ?  Sometimes that will make harder cert jobs a little easier to visualize.